# Illustrator Script: Generate a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I have been working on creating a system where I can export my swatches from Illustrator as a JSON object in order to allow for my simplicity when trying to update my App that I have created.

Using the illustrator scripting API I have managed to loop through all my swatches and generate an object. What I am attempting to do now is take this data and generate a JSON file with it. This is so that whenever I make colour updates to my App in illustrator it will immediately change everything when I run that script.

I have been making use of [Adobe Documentation](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/illustrator/sdk/CC2015_3/Illustrator%20JavaScript%20Scripting%20Reference.pdf) as well as a helpful site with it simplified and easier to navigate [Jongware](http://jongware.mit.edu/iljscs6html/iljscs6/pc_Document.html#saveAs).

The code overall looks like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86tqs33c/)

The code in question is the following. I am not sure if there is  way to generate the file without making use of the API. They seem to be using the same JS engine as a browser would but I am not 100% sure. Any advice would be great!

```
var file = new File('filename.txt');
file.saveAs('txt');
```

So the main question is how would I generate a new file locally that is able to store this object I have created? As the API isnt that clear on how to create a basic text file from the data I have created.

Comment: Little unsure what you're trying to find out here. On one hand, I wonder if you're stuck at the point of creating the JSON representation of the object you have, on the other hand I wonder if you're asking if there's a different way to create the file than your last snippet illustrates. There's not a single `?` character in your whole post, which reads more like a conversation than a concise attempt to extract a precise answer to a specific problem.

Comment: Aplogies. I have amended the question at the bottom and added the underlying problem. Basically when I want the script to run it must generate a .txt file that has all the data I have gathered.

Comment: why put the code in a fiddle if its only for example purposes and doesnt work. Include it in your question.

Comment: @factordog if youre creating `JSON` it shouldnt be a `.txt` file but a `.json` file.

Comment: @Craicerjack - a text file by any other extension would be just as plain. JSON is text, the extension is irrelevant except for tools that insist on holding one's hand and hampering one's freedom.

Comment: @factordog - does answer #2 help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477026/how-to-write-text-to-a-text-file-by-photoshop-javascript

Comment: @Craicerjack the fiddle is there to give you a basic understanding of the code. If I gave you everything you would need Illustrator, ExtendScript my swatches all running. Just been looking to see if there is an easy way to generate a file in JS and pass some data into it. I will take a look into that solution now enhzflep

Comment: @factordog I realise the fiddle is there to give a basic understanding. My question was why put it offsite and not include that code in the question above?

Comment: @Craicerjack Just didnt want a huge chunk of code when most of it is irrelevant to the question. The main part was the little piece that I did link along with links to the documentation.

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks for that source. Seems to work using the 4th method but will play around with it till i get the 2nd one working.

Comment: @factordog - A pleasure. Just use whatever works for you. I never read past the 2nd since it looked like it might help. - it could be the worst solution on the page for all I know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of the suggestion @enhzflep and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477026/how-to-write-text-to-a-text-file-by-photoshop-javascript).

I came to the final output of:

```
var file;
file = File.saveDialog('Export');
file.open('w');
file.write(JSON.stringify(colourObject));
file.close();
```

Making use of [Douglas Crockfords](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) JSON2 Pollyfill (As Illustrator scripts dont support .stringify) to create a stringify method I was able to create a JSON exported file.